# birt show list result with specific view

Tags: birt

I have got problem with my list. Actually i create list from database select, and i havent got any problem with that ...
But i have got problem with show resoults.

This is my list resoult:

```
L.p | Type | text | description    |
------------------------------------
1. | Text  |text1 | description 1  |
2. | Text  |text2 | description 2  |
3. | Text  |text3 | description 3  |
4. | Image |image1| description 4  |
5. | Image |image2| description 5  |
6. | Video |video1| description 6  |
7. | Video |video2| description 7  |
8. | Video |video3| description 8  |
9. | Video |video4| description 9  |
------------------------------------
```

But i need show this resoults like that :

```
L.p | Type | text | description    |
------------------------------------
1. | Text  |text1 | description 1  |
2. |       |text2 | description 2  |
3. |       |text3 | description 3  |
4. |       |      |                |
5. | Image |image1| description 4  |
6. |       |image2| description 5  |
7. |       |      |                |
8. | Video |video1| description 6  |
9. |       |video2| description 7  |
10.|       |video3| description 8  |
11.|       |video4| description9   |
12.|       |      |                |
13.|       |      |                |
14.|       |      |                |
15.|       |      |                |
16.|       |      |                |
17.|       |      |                |
18.|       |      |                |
19.|       |      |                |
20.|       |      |                |
------------------------------------
```

As you can see i have got:
1. empty row beetwen two different types.
2.Category is only in one line (first line)
3. min resoults is 20 so when my select return only 10 next ten is empty rows. But if i have got more than 20 resoults i show all.

How i can do that easy ? i am using birt 2.3.2 and eclipse plugin.

plz help

Answer (score 1):

select the table and you will see the **groups tab** in **property editor** through this you can group your result as you like.

Cheers

Comment: OK but its posible add empty row if row num < 35 ?

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the empty first row, select the cell with the "Type" data element in it and set the drop property, in the general tab of the property editor, to detail.  To get a minimum of 20 rows, the easiest way will probably be to add extra rows to your table footer and hide/show them based on the number of rows in your table.  Here is a link to an example that will show what I'm talking about with adding the extra rows to the footer.

http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1355-extending-a-table-to-a-certain-number-of-rows-with-alternating-row-color/

Answer (score 0):

Read about DataCubes and Cross Tabs in BIRT. They are meant for this exact same purpose.

They way I would do it is build a data cube with X groups being L.P, Type, text (in that same order) and Y measures being description. Then build a cross tab with this data cube.